# Can one deallocate stack memory on x86_64 by substracting from rbp?

Tags: stack, nasm, dynamic-memory-allocation

The title pretty much says it. I am writing an algorithm (and right now porting it into nasm) that would need to allocate lots (upwards of 8gb) of ram (as a severe tradeoff for cpu usage). On every iteration it stores an int onto the stack (for output and later usage). Then, periodically it could free a set of values but only from the bottom of the stack. Could this be done by simply decrementing the stack base (rbp)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A stack is a stack. You can push and pop values on the top but nothing more. You cannot deallocate anything from it in any other way.

Changing RBP doesn't do anything, it is just a helper register to use for the current stack frame. RSP shows the current top of the stack and moving that changes where the next value will be stored to or retrieved from within the stack. So you can drop a bunch of values from the top if needed, but not from the bottom.

If you have a need to temporarily store values and later release them then a circular buffer or blocks of regular memory would be a much better suited for that.

Comment: Kiitos, sami. Halki, poikki ja pinoon -vastaus.